# Checking if a css loads an external file

Tags: css

I am building a tool to minify and compile CSS files on-demand. The files can be in different folders, and I need them to be called from their original folder if they are referring to an external file (image, other css, font maybe?).

I wonder which strings I should look for. I only see `url(` and `@import`, but am pretty sure I am missing some.

Comment: Is something wrong with an existing minify tool?

Comment: In the case of CSS (not Sass which uses import to produce a combined CSS file from multiple Scss files) import is the only syntax used to effectively include style declarations within that CSS file - at least that I know of. There is of course nothing to stop the page author linking to multiple stylesheets separately within the document head. When you refer to compiling, are you referring to a pre-processor like Sass or LESS? CSS itself is declarative and not compiled.

Comment: I use an existing minifyer, but my files are located in different places, and I wish to minify together all the ones which don't rely on other files, and minify one by one the ones which do.

Comment: @pwdst: although I use a preprocessor for Sass and Less I am refering here to the following step which is minifying and grouping the CSS into a single file (but only for the ones with no external files)

Comment: I can personally strongly recommend Compass.app (http://compass.handlino.com/) for both minifying and combining multiple Scss files or partials into a single minified CSS output file - but you would need all of the files to be in the same directory both a) to be able do this and b) to ensure that the relative paths to background images etc. aren't broken. Is there a good reason to split the files into different locations? For $10 (or by just compiling from source for free) you could have an excellent out of the box solution.

Comment: @pwdst: I am building a CDN server used by several projects, hosting different versions of the same libraries, I can't think of a way of having one single location

Comment: To the person who wants to close this question: it's perfectly answerable by checking CSS2.1 and modules of CSS3 plus MSDN (Opera, Mozilla and WebKit have stuck to W3C syntax for a long time now, even for their proprietary properties). And if there exists another strange vendor, I don't think that OP would care.

Comment: @pwdst Compass.app sounds like a waste of $10 when you can get all of the features you mention from Compass itself.  The only thing Compass.app does for you is hide the scary command line.

Comment: @cimmanon I am well aware of that, and haven't claimed otherwise. I work on multiple projects with both front and back end development in ASP.NET using a variety of tools and languages. Compass.app makes it trivial to get started with Sass quickly (especially on a Windows machine which doesn't include prerequisites like Ruby out of the box) without having to worry about yet another syntax beyond Sass itself. I am used to spending hundreds or even thousands for good tooling (such as Resharper or Visual Studio) so $10 with free updates and 30% to charity is a price I'm more than willing to pay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of proprietary CSS: **`behavior`** which loads `.htc` (`.js` on some servers) for *that* browser. Also exists as [`-ms-behavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
EDIT: oops, `behavior` will use `url()` too, not `behavior()` as I previously wrote... My mistake. Ex:

```
.ie67 * {
  behavior: url('htc/boxsizing.htc');
}
```

I don't think that `filter` / `-ms-filter` can load an external resource; it'll rather apply to images and such (somebody correct me if I'm wrong).

In CSS2.1, external resources are [URIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html) so except @import (that must appear before anything else), I think your list is complete.

Comment: And I just found this behavior() in my css library! It would have broken at some stage. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Even if `behavior` is proprietary, `boxsizing.htc` or `css3pie.htc` are quite useful to name only 2 examples! ;)

Comment: And I was wrong: `behavior` also uses the `url()` syntax. I edited my answer accordingly